# customising share button, need to replace icon font with image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement following share button....

http://jquery-plugins.net/share-button-fast-and-beautiful-social-share-buttons

It works fine as it is but, i need to replace icon font with Image.

I tried to change few css properties but it doesn't work properly

http://jsfiddle.net/eu0tbjLo/4/

```
<div class="article-icon-box social-media-popup">
    <div class='share-button'> <img src="" alt="S"/></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to replace `font` with `image`? You mean `background` or `text`?

Comment: @WhiteAngel, rather than showing the icon & word `share` in side the div `share-button` i want to show an icon image only..

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, I think you should overwrite those css styles - https://github.com/carrot/share-button/wiki/CSS-Styles

Answer (score 2):

```
  Share.prototype.inject_icons = function() {
    return this.inject_stylesheet("https://www.sharebutton.co/fonts/v2/entypo.min.css");
  };
```

change this link in share.js with your css

Answer (score 1):

[see this link](https://github.com/carrot/share-button/wiki/Configuration-Options)

```
var share = new Share('.share-button', config);
config = {
ui: {
button_text:       // change the text of the button, [Default: `Share`]
icon_font:         // include the minified Entypo font set. [Default: `true`]
},}
```

Answer (score 0):

please make bg with '!important' property. do same as below for other icons

```
`.share-button.sharer-0 .social li[class*=pinterest] {
background: url('../images/pinterest.png') no-repeat #c5282f !important;
display: block;
}`
```